# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, java-11, look-and-feel, jide

I am trying to use

LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension();

and get the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsLookAndFeel
        at com.jidesoft.plaf.LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension(Unknown Source)
        at com.jidesoft.plaf.LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension(Unknown Source)
        at com.jidesoft.plaf.LookAndFeelFactory.installJideExtension(Unknown Source)
```

I am importing this library import com.jidesoft.plaf.LookAndFeelFactory and ./gradlew -q clean build working properly but I get the error when I try to run my project.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe a silly comment, but it looks like you're trying to load a Windows L&F while not running within a Windows environment. In that case it's highly unlikely that the JVM contains that L&F.

Comment: This Windows L&F was never part of the official API so a custom look and feel directly accessing those classes always was a hack.